# Struggling to convert SQL query to it's LINQ equivalent - Multiple joins, groupings and aggregate functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query that gives me expected results in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT 
    u.DisplayName,
    up.ColorPreferences,
    SUM(rt.Score) AS Points,
    COUNT(*) AS Plans,
    MAX(pl.Created) AS MaxDate
FROM 
    [dbo].[Users] u
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[PlanLogs] pl ON u.Id = pl.UserId
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ResourceTypes] rt ON pl.ResourceTypeId = rt.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[UserProfile] up ON pl.UserId = up.UserId
GROUP BY 
    u.DisplayName, up.ColorPreferences;
```

an I have the following working linq query:

```
from u in _context.Users
join pl in _context.PlanLogs on u.Id equals pl.UserId
join rt in _context.ResourceTypes on pl.ResourceTypeId equals rt.ID
join up in _context.UserProfile on pl.UserId equals up.UserId
group rt by new { u.DisplayName, up.ColorPreferences} into g
select new
{
DisplayName = g.Key.DisplayName,
ColorPrefs = g.Key.ColorPreferences,
Points = g.Sum(x => x.Score),
Plans = g.Count()
};
```

As you can see, it is missing MaxDate. I can't get access to MaxDate because g contains properties from rt. I've tried the following and i get "Value does not fall within the expected range"

```
from u in _context.Users
join pl in _context.PlanLogs on u.Id equals pl.UserId
join rt in _context.ResourceTypes on pl.ResourceTypeId equals rt.ID
join up in _context.UserProfile on pl.UserId equals up.UserId
group new { rt, pl } by new { u.DisplayName, up.ColorPreferences} into g
select new
{
DisplayName = g.Key.DisplayName,
ColorPrefs = g.Key.ColorPreferences,
Points = g.Sum(x => x.rt.Score),
Plans = g.Count()
MaxDate = g.Max(m => m.pl.Created)
};
```

How do i add MaxDate to the results?

Thanks

Comment: The second attempt should work. What EF is this (6, Core, what version)? Can we see the exception stack trace?

Comment: I see you are doing an inner `join` but is it possible that some values of `m.pl.Created` are `null`? Perhaps if you did `g.Where(m => m.pl.Created != null).Max(m => m.pl.Created)`? Are you getting a warning that `Max` will be executed locally?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the max value from pl.created on your first linq query? why are you grouping by rt and not the whole result? try this instead :

```
from u in _context.Users
join pl in _context.PlanLogs on u.Id equals pl.UserId
join rt in _context.ResourceTypes on pl.ResourceTypeId equals rt.ID
join up in _context.UserProfile on pl.UserId equals up.UserId
group u by new { u.DisplayName, up.ColorPreferences} into g
select new
{
  DisplayName = g.Key.DisplayName,
  ColorPrefs = g.Key.ColorPreferences,
  Points = g.Sum(x => x.Score),
  Plans = g.Count(),
  MaxDate = g.Max(m => m.pl.Created)
};
```

Comment: thanks for the reponse, unfortunately what you've suggested makes perfect sense but is syntatically incorrect. You can't simply have "group by new". Invalid expression term by

Comment: yes, then i only get the properties listed that belong to the users table. I used rt to be able to get to Score

Answer (score 0):

I solevd this in the end. I needed to pass the specific columns to the group not the whole table:

```
group new { rt.Score, pl.Created } by..
```

rather than

```
group new { rt, pl } by...
```

Working query:

```
from u in _context.Users
join pl in _context.PlanLogs on u.Id equals pl.UserId
join rt in _context.ResourceTypes on pl.ResourceTypeId equals rt.ID
join up in _context.UserProfile on pl.UserId equals up.UserId
group new { rt.Score, pl.Created } by new { u.DisplayName, up.ColorPreferences } into g
select new
{
DisplayName = g.Key.DisplayName,
ColorPrefs = g.Key.ColorPreferences,
Points = g.Sum(i => i.Score),
Plans = g.Count(),
MaxCreated = g.Max(i => i.Created).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
}
```